# Using JPA with Hibernate implementation: entityManager.remove - not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am using JPA over `Hibernate 4.1.4.Final` implementation. My problem is that I can't get `EntityManager#remove()` working. All other: update, insert, select operation are working just fine except this one.

My `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence-unit name="myEntityManager">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>core.entity.Answer</class>
    <class>core.entity.BaseEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My `Answer` entity: (BaseEntity class just holds the primary key - ID)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Answer extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_VALUE")
    private String answerValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Question question;                

    //overrided equals, hascode, toString 
    // all getters and setters
}
```

When calling:

```
public void remove(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.remove(this.entityManager.merge(entity));
}
```

Also tried:

```
this.entityManager.remove(entity);
```

And:

```
T ref = entityManager.getReference(entityClass, primaryKey);
entityManager.remove(ref);
```

No luck :( it is not deleting the record of `Answer` from the database.

I am using Spring configuration to configure the entity manager like this:

```
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myEntityManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

`remove` is called in the method which is annotated with `@Transactional` annotation. So it shouldn't be transactions issue.

I have enabled Hibernate SQL logging, all the other logging. I am not seeing anywhere that `delete` query would be executed or any error at all.

And I am really out of options here. Please advice.

**EDIT**

Maybe this will also help:

I am getting the list of answers from the other entity. The answers are defined like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "evaluationPart")
private List<Answer> answers = new LinkedList<>();
```

Calling remove like this:

```
List<Answer> answers = evaluationPart.getAnswers();
if (answers != null && answers.size() > 0) {
    for (Answer answer : answers) {
        answerFacade.remove(answer); //This calls enetityManager.remove
    }
}
```

Comment: And your other Create/Update methods all work ok and persist as expected? are those methods in the same class and using the same setup?

Comment: Yes. Everything else is working, everything is the same for other operations.

Comment: @rhinds I've updated the question. Maybe you'd be able to see the problem now.

Comment: any errors in the server logs

Comment: No, nothing related to errors at all, no errors, just usual hibernate stuff and SQL..

Comment: Can you double check that there is a valid transaction when you are calling teh entitymanager remove function - try and log the output from: TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()

Comment: It's been 2 years. Have you found out why remove() didn't work? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be out of the topic but these can be the issues for the problem

**First Reason** - 
    No cascadeType defined in this entry

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Question question;
```

**Second Reason** (More of a suggestion)

As the linkedlist of Answer is mapped to the Question object, deleting a single object from the list directly is not recommended as a good practice. Better remove the element from the linked list and then update/merge the question object which will perform the remove operation automatically on the Answer table.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No cascade type is defined because I don't want this object to be cascaded in any way :) that's fine. Your second reason gave a way to the solution. Yes I don't need to call entityManager.remove if I am removing it from the list, so that worked. Thanks. Still can't fully understand why hibernate did not clear the persistence context. Maybe because the objects were lazy loaded...

Comment: Just had the same issue, it would be nice if Hibernate would at least yell at you for removing a list item by calling em.remove(ref). Oh well, lesson learned.