# EntityManager.Remove doesn't remove entity with ManyToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new Hibernate/JPA. I have a problem in deleting child element from parent element. Below are my entity classes SourceMaster and SegmentMaster.

```
@Entity
public class SourceMaster implements Serializable{
    @EmbeddedId
    private SourceMasterKey id;//Primary Key is composite key. Combination of SOURCE_ID&DOMAIN_ID
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "sourceTable") //I don't want to delete children
    private List<SegmentMaster> segmentList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class SegmentMaster implements Serializable{
    @EmbeddedId
    private SegmentMasterKey id;//Primary Key is composite key. Combination of SEGMENT_NAME&CA_DOMAIN_ID
    @ManyToOne (optional = false) //FK to SourceMaster table
    @JoinColumns({
         @JoinColumn(name = "SOURCE_ID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "SOURCE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
         @JoinColumn(name = "DOMAIN_ID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "DOMAIN_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private SourceMaster sourceTable; 
}
```

Delegate Classes

```
public class SourceMasterDelegate{ 
 sourceMasterDAO.delete(SourceMaster); // Works as intended, returns me integrity constraint violated - child record found
}

public class SegmentMasterDelegate{
sourceMasterDAO.delete(SegmentMaster);//Problem here. It is not deleting SegmentMaster record, not giving exception or not logging any exception.

//It executes select statements on SegmentMaster and SourceMaster tables. but delete Query executing is never seen. 
}


public class HDAOImpl implements GenericDAO<T> {
    @Transactional
    public void delete(T object) {
        entityManager.remove(object);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in association? why I am not able to delete child record in this scenario?

This was nearest answer I got but this didn't work or I did wrong may be -> [Using JPA with Hibernate implementation: entityManager.remove - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679620/using-jpa-with-hibernate-implementation-entitymanager-remove-not-working)

Any pointers would be great! Kindly suggest

Comment: Have you tried switching on low-level (DEBUG or TRACE) logging for Hibernate or Spring. Any errors? Try switching on SQL logging to see if any SQL is generated. Before you delete the child, do you remove it from the list of children in the parent?

Comment: Yes logging is set. (oracle.hibernate.show_sql=true)
It is showing select statements only. 
so removing children from parent -> any suggestions ? I might not done or not sure please help

Comment: So, before deleting the `SegmentMaster` child, do you remove it from the `segmentList` in the parent? Or is it still in the list when you delete it?

Comment: Thank you for response . you are right I didn't remove from the segmentList in parent. It still in the list.  Actually I am not doing anything with segmentList. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, the state of the Entities has to reflect the data, so if the child is still in the list, Hibernate thinks you still want to keep it.

Comment: Yes I got it. THanks Duncan. That was a great tip.